# Word Interop object and VB.net: a visible/invisible issue

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

First, pls forgive me if this question seems basic to many of you but here's something I just can't figure at my humble level of expertise:

I develop a quite large Winforms application which makes intensive use of Word "templates" such as invoices, labels etc...
Everything goes smooth with documents being created with hidden Word objects, but as soon as I fire up Word separately from my application for, say, creating another document, **the hidden Word object pops up, is made visible and requires focus...**

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks much for any hints you may have

Cheers

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what code is used to create another Word document which causes the issue. Anyway, the [Application.Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.visible) property allows hiding Microsoft Word, for example:

```
Application.Visible = False
```

Comment: Well...I obviously use oWord.Visible = false but as soon as anything else gets activated, the object window still pops up... The fact is I am filling contentcontrol placeholders with data and I think I've read somewhare that the fact that the doc is activated may bring it to top, so....Thanks anyway!